# How can I destroy a Bitmap object on touch in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android programming, so I hope I make sense. I have a number of Bitmap objects that I would like to erase upon touch, and draw something else. What would be the best way to do it? I was originally thinking to destroy the object, but it may be redundant if I will be drawing another object anyways. 
Looking for a point in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Gallery` ([Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)) layout to display your objects. Then use `onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` as event for replacing the object.

Comment: Hmm, that tutorial is for a static gallery. Could I apply it to moving bitmaps?

Comment: @NVtool: The tutorial uses ImageView, which can load images from various sources such as resources or content providers. You can use whatever suits your needs best.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out :)